# Problema com módulo "confirmable" da gem "devise" em RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Estava implementando a [gem Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) no RubyOnRails e tudo estava funcionando perfeitamente.

Aí eu fui adicionar o módulo "confirmable". Tomei os seguintes passos:

Adicionei `:confirmable` em `Usuarios.rb`:

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         # adicionado por mim
         :confirmable
end
```

Criei o migration file:

```
class AddConfirmableToUsuarios < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:usuarios) do |t|
      t.string :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string :unconfirmed_email
    end
  end
end
```

Nas views eu tive que corrigir algumas urls adicionando `usuario` nos helpers, por exemplo:

```
new_confirmation_path(resource_name)
# para
new_usuario_confirmation_path(resource_name)
```

Porém ao enviar o formulário em `views/devise/confirmation/new.html.erb` eu recebo o código 406 "not accptable" e o erro `ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::ConfirmationsController#create`. Apesar disso o e-mail de confirmação é enviado e o link enviado é valido e a conta pode ser validada.

Segue o formulário abaixo:

```
<h2>Resend confirmation instructions</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: usuario_confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Resend confirmation instructions" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça seu form assim:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
```

O problema está na rota, creio eu.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, deu certo. Valeu :)